# Spring Kafka filter not filtering consumer record

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to filter ConsumerRecord messages before consuming, based on the content on one of the fields in the ConsumerRecord.

Sample consumer record before applying filter is(look for GP_ID in the value)  :

```
 ConsumerRecord(topic = jdbc-project, partition = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1551118248440, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 69, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = {"GP_ID": {"bytes": "@"}, "PROJECT_ID": {"bytes": "\u001E\u008C"}, "START_DATE": 1009843200000, "END_DATE": 1041292800000, "TITLE": "Project- FPH", "STATUS_CODE": "INACTIVE"})

KafkaRecordVO(projectId=7820, gpId=64)
```

When I set the recordFilterStrategy as below in kafkaListenerContainerFactory() :

```
@Bean
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryProject() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(new RecordFilterStrategy<String, GenericRecord>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> consumerRecord) {
            long gpId= KafkaRecordVO.convertByteBufferToLong(consumerRecord.value().get("GP_ID"));
            if(gpId == 10766L || gpId == 10823L || gpId == 10459L || gpId == 10649L)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    });
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    return factory;
}
```

KafkaRecordVO.convertByteBufferToLong is converting the bytebuffer value to long value.

This is evaluating correctly, and returning true/false.

But,when it is consumed by Kafka listener as below :

```
@KafkaListener(id = "project", topics = "jdbc-project", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryProject")
public void consumeProject(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record,Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    log.debug(record.toString());
    KafkaRecordVO recordVo = new KafkaRecordVO().projectId(record.value().get("PROJECT_ID"))
                                                .budgetYear(record.value().get("GP_ID"));
    log.debug(recordVo.toString());
}
```

This is returning the record stripping the value of the field I filtered on : "GP_ID"

These are the sample logs produced after applying filter (look for GP_ID in the value) :

```
ConsumerRecord(topic = jdbc-project, partition = 0, offset = 171275, CreateTime = 1551118279371, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 181, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = { "GP_ID": {"bytes": ""}, "PROJECT_ID": {"bytes": "\u0005â^"}, "START_DATE": 1470009600000, "END_DATE": 1532995200000, "TITLE": "Project 2016 - 2016", "STATUS_CODE": "INACTIVE"})

KafkaRecordVO(projectId=385630, gpId=0)
```

I get this in the log with other field: "GP_ID": {"bytes": ""} in my kafkaListener for this topic. How to not strip off the value ? What is wrong here ?

**UPDATE:** The issue happened when I used a utility method to convert bytes to long. It was setting the position to end of the array. That's why it is returning empty array:

```
public static Long convertByteBufferToLong(Object byteBuff) {
    //After adding below line, the issue got resolved
    ByteBuffer buf = ((ByteBuffer) byteBuff).duplicate();
    byte[] arr = new byte[buf.remaining()];
    buf.get(arr);
    BigInteger bi =new BigInteger(1,arr);
    return bi.longValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting makes no sense; the filter adapter has this code...

```
@Override
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<K, V> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
    if (!filter(consumerRecord)) {
        switch (this.delegateType) {
            case ACKNOWLEDGING_CONSUMER_AWARE:
                this.delegate.onMessage(consumerRecord, acknowledgment, consumer);
                break;
            case ACKNOWLEDGING:
                this.delegate.onMessage(consumerRecord, acknowledgment);
                break;
            case CONSUMER_AWARE:
                this.delegate.onMessage(consumerRecord, consumer);
                break;
            case SIMPLE:
                this.delegate.onMessage(consumerRecord);
        }
    }
    else {
        ackFilteredIfNecessary(acknowledgment);
    }
}
```

It performs no manipulation of the record.

Try running in a debugger to see if you can see what's happening.

Comment: Yes, it's not related to api. There was an issue with a utility method. Updated my question. Thanks for taking time to look at the issue.